# cell inherit from different according ios version using macro

Tags: ios, macros

As described ,I want a cell inherit from different super according iOS platform version,I wrote this

```
   #define IOS_7    ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue>=7.0?YES:NO)
   #if IOS_7
   #define SuperCell  UITableViewCell
   #else
   #define SuperCell  EditTableViewCell
   #endif
   @interface AlbumCell : SuperCell <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

But it gives an error,so what should I do to make this work?

Comment: Think about it: Macro definitions and the interface declaration are read at *compile time*. The iOS version is evaluated at *run time*.